# Jenkins scripted pipeline does not fetch the test result if unit test fails

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have gradle based java projects with junit tests which I'm building CI jobs for. I was successfully able to integrate slack with Jenkins using slack Slack Notification plugin.

Jenkins Version : 2.173
Slack Notification version : 2.20

The jenkins CI is a scripted pipeline, which has the below code:

```
stage('Test') {
        def slackHelper = new com.xyz.jenkins.libraries.SlackNotifier(env)
        try {
            sh "./gradlew test"
            junit 'build/test-results/test/*.xml'
        } finally {
            AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction =  currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)

            slackHelper.getTestStatuses(currentBuild)
            slackSend(channel: '#ci-cd', attachments: slackHelper.buildUnitTestSlackNotificationMessage())
        }
    }
```

SlackNotifier is a library which has the below code:

```
/**
 * Calculates test result as a string
 * @param currentBuild : jenkins object, should be passed from jenkins pipeline script
 * @return the final test result as a string
 */
@NonCPS
def getTestStatuses(currentBuild) {
    final AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
    if (testResultAction != null) {
        this.total = testResultAction.totalCount
        this.failed = testResultAction.failCount
        this.skipped = testResultAction.skipCount
        this.passed = total - failed - skipped
    }
}
```

buildUnitTestSlackNotificationMessage does this in the same class:

```
def buildUnitTestSlackNotificationMessage() {
        final JSONObject unitTestResult = new JSONObject()
        unitTestResult.put("fallback", this.jenkinsEnvironment.JOB_NAME + "with build#" + this.jenkinsEnvironment.BUILD_NUMBER + "finish with unit test result : Passed: " + this.passed + " | Failed: " + this.failed + " | Skipped: " + this.skipped )
        unitTestResult.put("color", this.getUnitTestReportColor())
        unitTestResult.put("pretext", "Message from CI job: " + this.jenkinsEnvironment.JOB_NAME + "#" + this.jenkinsEnvironment.BUILD_NUMBER)
        unitTestResult.put("title", "BuildLog")
        unitTestResult.put("title_link", "<<<JenkinsHost>>>" + this.jenkinsEnvironment.JOB_NAME + "/" + this.jenkinsEnvironment.BUILD_NUMBER  + "/console")
        unitTestResult.put("text", "Passed: " + this.passed +  " | Failed: " + this.failed + " | Skipped: " + this.skipped)
        unitTestResult.put("image_url", this.getLogoURL())
        this.attachments.add(unitTestResult)
        return this.attachments.toString()
    }
```

All is well when all the tests pass. But when tests fail I get the below notification:

```
Message from CI job: <<<JobName>>>#47
BuildLog
Passed: null | Failed: null | Skipped: null
```

It turns out `testResultAction` is null when any unit tests fail here.

And I'm unable to come to the bottom of this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer in reddit, credit goes to : /u/Bodumin

And here is the root cause, I'm quoting him here :

`Move the junit step into the finally. What's likely happening is that test returns a non 0 (error) status so it fails it of the try.`

So, the scripted pipeline looks like below:

```
stage('Test') {
        def slackHelper = new com.xyz.jenkins.libraries.SlackNotifier(env)
        try {
            sh "./gradlew test"
        } finally {
            junit 'build/test-results/test/*.xml'
            AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction =  currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)

            slackHelper.getTestStatuses(currentBuild)
            slackSend(channel: '#ci-cd', attachments: slackHelper.buildUnitTestSlackNotificationMessage())
        }
    }
```